# Is it a good React pattern to use ES2016 Property Initializer Syntax in ES6 classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-next

I watched a lesson  about [[Use ES2016 Property Initializer Syntax in ES6 classes]](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-use-es2016-property-initializer-syntax-in-es6-classes)  on egghead.io, and I'm not quite sure - is it a good practise to use it.
Here's a regular stateful React component from upper mentioned lesson:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      todos: [],
      currentTodo: ''
    }
  }
this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this)

  handleInputChange (evt) {
    this.setState({
      currentTodo: evt.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
    ...
          <TodoForm handleInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
            currentTodo={this.state.currentTodo}
          <TodoList todos={this.state.todos}/>
    ...
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the same refactored component using ES2016 syntax:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    todos: [],
    currentTodo: ''
  }

  handleInputChange = (evt) => {
    this.setState({
      currentTodo: evt.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {

    return (
    ...
          <TodoForm handleInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
            currentTodo={this.state.currentTodo}
          <TodoList todos={this.state.todos}/>
    ...
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is a very good practice to use it. 
There is no reason to manually do a bind when the property initializer does it for you: the code is much cleaner and you don't scatter the code with other one line instructions.

Comment: But currently it's not very popular, actually I haven't seen it yet. And I suppose It's not recommended to use in production code

Comment: @TarasYaremkiv It's in lots of examples that get posted here every day. Why would it not be recommended to use in production?

Comment: I think because ES7 is not as widely supported nowadays as ES6. Actually all I have to do to use this in Webpack is to npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2016 and change baber.rc to "presets": ["es2016"] ?

Comment: @TarasYaremkiv But this is ES6, not ES7. Don't really understand your point

Comment: Hmm) beginning of the lesson's name "Use ES2016 Property Initializer Syntax" confused me. I thought it is ES2016 not E2015

Comment: @TarasYaremkiv: The feature is neither part of ES2015 nor ES2016. [It's a stage 2 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposals), i.e. it may be part of next year's release (ES2018) or it may not. It doesn't belong to any release yet.

Comment: *"Yes it is a very good practice to use it."* I disagree. Whether using an experimental feature, whose behavior or syntax might change, is good or not needs to be evaluated on a case by case basis.

Comment: @felix-kling It would be nice - if you write you opinion like a separate answer or at least post a link to duplicated question - if have been asked already. BTW In the lesson where I saw it first, an author said that Create-react-app let us to use it, but as far as I understood , "babel-preset-stage-2" is needed to use that

Comment: @TarasYaremkiv: Presets are just collections of plugins to make the configuration easier. What is really needed is `babel-plugin-transform-class-properties`, which create-react-app uses. Personally I think this question should be closed as too subjective, sorry.